# How to set a launcher icon for the self-contained JavaFX2 application?

Tags: icons, javafx-2, native, launcher, self-contained

I've successfully created a native deploy ant script to make a .deb from my JavaFX2 application. However I can't seem to put a launcher icon for it. I had followed 2 steps:

1.Set the classpath for the ant-javafx to include the current directory and put in my base app dir my icon file, Aurica.png ( classpath=".:/home/aureliangtx/programs/java/lib/ant-javafx.jar" ). However, the ant verbose output for the fx:deploy states:

Using default package resource [menu icon] (add package/linux/Aurica.png to the class path to customize)

2.I've tried to set the fx:icon in fx:deploy as, stated by Igor here (https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#7), but the outcome is the same.

```
<fx:info>
    <fx:icon href="Aurica.png" />
</fx:info>
```

Is it a bug on Linux maybe, or I am doing something wrong here?

Regards,
Aurelian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this... it was a big mistake from my part. When I first installed Ant I also copied the ant-javafx library into Ant's lib folder. Also I was redefining it in my build.xml through taskdef, so I guess at class loading, the first jar was loaded and as a result my settings ( such as current dir classpath from the taskdef) were ignored. I apologize for stupidity...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a "package" directory in the base app directory, a "linux" directory inside the "package" directory and finally put Aurica.png in the "linux" directory.

Comment: i have this structure but my maven ant plugin is not picking it

Comment: Perhaps you can turn on verbose mode to see what resources it's picking up when making the package.  Section '6.3.3.1 Preparing Custom Resources' in http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1308687 has more information.

Comment: yes i had already did this here is output.
   Using custom package resource [application icon] (loaded from file D:\RPAS\cl
ient\java\client\src\main\deploy\package\windows\java-client-5.2.0-SNAPSHOT.ico)
  Config files are saved to C:\Users\MUHAMM~1.MUB\AppData\Local\Temp\build143910
4108930099215.fxbundler\windows. Use them to customize
  Using default package resource [WiX config file] (add package/windows/java-cli
ent-5.2.0-SNAPSHOT.wxs to the class path to customize)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973919/where-substitute-custome-resource-icon-wix-and-wxs-file-for-javafx-2-when-dep